# How do I subset for specific transfers (A to/from B pairs) in a long list in R?

Tags: r, survey, matching

I have a dataframe from an On-Board Survey with weights and variables for up to 8 used lines: VEH1 through VEH8.  The lines are labeled "MT-..1" through "MT-902".  I want to know how many transfers there are between two specific lines.

I thought I would subset for all records where "MT-802" either proceeds or follows "MT-901", but I don't see how to do even that.

Comment: Can you describe the data.frame in more detail? That is, what are the dimensions, column names, and row names?

Comment: There are 130 columns, 33780 rows.  Important variables are SAMPN {Sample Number} expwgt {expansion Weight} ROUTE {surveyed route} and VEH1 through VEH8 {sequence of Routes used for Trip}

reflecting further, It may be good to also limit to cases where ROUTE is also one of the two desired routes, since the weights expand to ROUTE ridership....

Answer (score 1):

This really belongs on stackoverflow but here is something which may give you some pointers:

```
t1 <- "SAMPN  expwgt ROUTE VEH1   VEH2   VEH3  
       1      5      AB    MT-..1 MT-..2 NA 
       2      9      AC    MT-..1 MT-..2 MT-..3
       3      3      BC    MT-..2 MT-..3 NA
       4      3      BA    MT-..2 MT-..1 NA 
       5      4      CA    MT-..3 MT-..2 MT-..1
       6      4      CB    MT-..3 MT-..4 NA 
       7      2      CA    MT-..4 NA     NA"
indat <- read.table(textConnection(t1), header = TRUE)

colvf <- 4 # column of first VEH in indat
colvl <- 6 # column of last  VEH in indat
tapply( rep( indat$expwgt, colvl-colvf ), 
        list( as.matrix(indat[ ,colvf:(colvl-1)]), 
              as.matrix(indat[ ,(colvf+1):colvl]) ),  sum)
```

which produces

```
       MT-..1 MT-..2 MT-..3 MT-..4
MT-..1     NA     14     NA     NA
MT-..2      7     NA     12     NA
MT-..3     NA      4     NA      4
MT-..4     NA     NA     NA     NA
```